# How to remove case sensitiveness of edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have to send the package name to other application. That is done successfully. But when i write the package in edit text. The edit text is case sensitive. so how can i remove that?
Is there any option to make changes in main.xml or i have to do it pro grammatically. Please suggest.

Comment: replace to characters with small case, use toLowerCase() method.

Comment: Still not working. Because the package name consists upper case and lowercase both. But i need it should accept in all conditions where i write just in lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you check the package name is so and so, use

```
String textEntered=editText.getText().toString();
if(textEntered.equalsIgnoreCase("package name"))
{
    //proceed the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `.toLowerCase()` on the `String` before sending it?

Comment: Still not working. Because the package name consists upper case and lowercase both. But i need it should accept in all conditions where i write just in lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 0):

```
String txt = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

Now use **txt** where ever you want...

Comment: Still not working. Because the package name consists upper case and lowercase both. But i need it should accept in all conditions where i write just in lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to send package name in lower case use

```
yourString.toLowerCase();
```

before sending

adding After reading your comment above. 
I think you are comparing the package names, In that case . use

```
 onePackagename.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherPackageName);
```